# ClientError: (AccessDenied) when calling the sts:AssumeRole operation for the AWS account used to connect Amazon SP-API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-mws, aws-sts

I want to connect to the Amazon SP-API. It says in the documentation that I need to create an AWS account and add the necessary permissions so I can use it to connect the Amazon SP-API. Our developer profile is approved and we have registered our application. I have attempted to connect with these credentials using this  [python SP-API library](https://python-amazon-sp-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) .

However, I have an error which says:

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:iam::<account_id>:user/username is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::<account_id>:user/username

I think the cause of my error is my permission policy. Is there something wrong with the following policies on how it was declared?

```
//STS-POLICY
{ 
    "Version": "2012-10-17", 
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid":  "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect" : "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::<account_id>:user/<username>"
        }
    ]
}
```

```
//EXECUTE-API-POLICY
{ 
    "Version": "2012-10-17", 
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid":  "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect" : "Allow",
            "Action": "execute-api:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api::<account_id>:*/*/*/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are tring to use AssumeRole with STS-Policy, Rosource should be role instead of user.

Change this line in STS-Policy

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:iam::<account_id>:user/<username>"
```

to like this.

```
Resource": "arn:aws:iam::<account_id>:role/<rolename>"
```

See the section "Example policy that grants permission to assume a role" of [this aws doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_control-access_enable-create.html).